# PictureCount does not change

Tags: java

the code is used to create an application which shows picture and if your anwser is correct your supposed to see the next picture but the pictureCount does not go up. all of the variables ar declared after the main class and i created an Actionlistener to check if the awnser is correct.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {new Main().test();}

public int pictureCount = 1;
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JButton button1 = new JButton("Submit");
JTextField  text = new JTextField();
JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\practicum 3\\" + pictureCount + ".jpg"));

void test(){

    button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if(text.getText().equals("5")){
                pictureCount++;
                new Main().test();
            }
        }
    });

    panel1.add(button1);
    panel2.add(text);
    panel3.add(label);

    text.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,50));
    panel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 200));
    panel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 100));
    panel3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 450));

    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, panel1);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panel2);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, panel3);

    frame.setSize(1000,750);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setTitle("Operation Screen");
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}
```

}

Comment: This is when you should add a print statement in your actionPerformed() method to see what the value of pictureCount is after it increments...

Comment: after the action it is still 1 but i dont know why

Comment: Is the correct answer always equal to 5?

Comment: Can you type this in your actionPerformed() method: `System.out.println(text.getText());`

Comment: i just tried it the system prints the number i have typed

Comment: Invoking `new Main().test()` you're creating a new frame whenever you click button1. Since pictureCount is not static, the value increased is related to the older frame and the new frame still has the value of one. If you change pictureCount  to static, it might work, but mind that it is not the way to go. You should reset the labels icon dinamically intead of  making pictureCount static and recreating the frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read in all the pictures as ImageIcons into an array or ArrayList, say called `imageIconArray` and then display imageIconArray[0] in your JLabel when you start.

When the button is pressed, increment pictureCount, and then reset the JLabel's icon via its `setIcon(...)` method:

```
// in the ActionListener code:
pictureCount++;
label.setIcon(imageIconArray[pictureCount];
```

Whatever you do, don't create a new Main object, despite what others might say. Why create a new GUI when all you need to do is swap displayed images?